# Named pipe can't connect for second time

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I have a client-server pipe processes, and when I try to connect at the first time, everything's OK, but when I start my client process again without restarting the server I cannot connect with PIPE_BUSY error, though GetOverlappedResult succeeds on the server, but waitforsingleobject doesn't signal that somebody connected and the message is empty of course.

```
std::wstring buffer;
while (true) {
    // pinging here...
    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 2000);

    if (result == WAIT_FAILED) {
        std::wcout << result << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    if (result == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        // always here 
    }

    ResetEvent(hEvent);

    DWORD bytesTransferred;

    OVERLAPPED ov;
    ZeroMemory( & ov, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    ov.hEvent = hEvent;

    if (GetOverlappedResult(pipe(), & ov, & bytesTransferred, TRUE) == 0) // FAILED
    {
        return; // we do never get here...
    } else {
        ZeroMemory( & ov, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

        DWORD bytesToRead = 0;

        BOOL pingPipe;

        Timer timer(1000);

        while (!bytesToRead || !pingPipe) {
            if (!timer.in()) {
                break;
            }

            pingPipe = PeekNamedPipe(pipe(), NULL, 0, NULL, & bytesToRead, NULL);
        }

        buffer.resize(sizeof(TCHAR) * bytesToRead);

        if (!ReadFile(pipe(), & buffer[0], bytesToRead, & bytesTransferred, & ov) && timer.in()) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                continue;
            }

            return;
        }

        // data here
        std::wcout << buffer << std::endl;
    }
}

DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe());
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a lot of key code in your post (which I assume is a snippet of a random bit of the end of the server side?). Please construct and post a [full example](http://sscce.org/). In doing so you may discover the problem, but at the bare minimum you'll give the actual needed info for others to help.

Comment: call `GetOverlappedResult` kill asynchronous logic

Comment: That said I suspect your misunderstanding of `GetOverlappedResult` and your random packing of your `OVERLAPPED` structure with `hEvent` is the core issue, as well as you not actually starting a proper overlapped operation (you don't just fill your own `OVERLAPPED`, you have to get it from e.g. `ReadFile` which will fill in the event handle and such *for* you) where the event is presumably being triggered on incoming connection and so you're actually blocking on `GetOverlappedResult` until somebody tries to connect or something like that.

Comment: Per the [Named Pipe Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592.aspx) documentation: "**A named pipe client uses the `CreateFile` function to open a handle to a named pipe. **If the pipe exists but all of its instances are busy, `CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and the `GetLastError` function returns `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`**. When this happens, the named pipe client uses the `WaitNamedPipe` function to wait for an instance of the named pipe to become available.*"  ...

Comment: ... The server pipe could be busy because your client's error handling is bypassing `DisconnectNamedPipe()` to release the pipe.  Or it could be because your server is not calling `CreateNamedPIpe()` enough times.  Who knows.  You did not provide any of the relevant code showing how you are creating the server pipe and how the client is connecting to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell precisely what `hEvent` is since you left out all your initialization code, but you are using `GetOverlappedResult` incorrectly, and all bets are pretty much off at that point:

```
OVERLAPPED ov;
ZeroMemory( & ov, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
ov.hEvent = hEvent;

if (GetOverlappedResult(pipe(), & ov, & bytesTransferred, TRUE) == 0) ...
```

This isn't how you do that. You don't declare an `OVERLAPPED` and pass it off brand new to `GetOverlappedResult`. You have to actually *start* an overlapped operation (a read, a write, a connect, whatever), e.g. passing the `OVERLAPPED` to `ReadFile` or something first. And the event handle you give it is generally an event that you've created that's *dedicated* to that overlapped task, not one that is also in use by whatever else.

It's the equivalent of you walking up to a random stranger on the street and saying, out of nowhere, "So, did you get that thing I asked for?".

You're attempting to complete an overlapped operation that you haven't started, and you're using an event handle that you are presumably also using to check for incoming connections or something, too. So it's pretty much up in the air what's going to happen.

So you have two options:

1. Read [this tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/165693-microsoft-working-with-overlapped-io/) (which I haven't verified for correctness but at a glance it looks fine), [this overview of overlapped I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx), and [the MS example of named pipe servers with overlapped I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365603(v=vs.85).aspx), then read it all again until you understand it, or
2. Stop using overlapped I/O. Which is what I recommend for now just to get the concepts down.

In addition to the above there may be further issues on your client side as well, but you have not shown the code for that. You may want to double check it against the relevant docs to make sure everything's OK on that end as well. Also as far as missing code goes, you'll want to verify that you're creating the pipe in overlapped mode on the server side by passing the appropriate flags on creation (can't look up, on phone for this edit, but check pipe creation api docs).

Comment: Note btw that if you start an overlapped operation then immediately go on to GetOverlappedResult without doing anything else in between, you might as well not use overlapped IO and save yourself the complexity. It's very useful when you need the asynchronicity, but when you don't a simple synchronous operation will suffice.